# При нажатии на кнопку меняется текст

Tags: swift

У меня создана кнопка с проигрыванием музыки, нужно чтобы при нажатии не только музыка включалась, но и текст менялся в кнопке, сейчас у меня такой код:

```html
let button:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
                button.setTitle("ON", forState: .Normal)
                button.setTitle("OF", forState: .Normal)

                button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
                button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTap:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                buttons.append(button)

func buttonTap(sender:UIButton){
        if (sender.tag == 1){

            if isPlaying {
                completeAudioPlayer?.stop()
                isPlaying = false
                
                sender.currentTitle == "OF"
                
            } else {
                completeAudioPlayer?.play()
                isPlaying = true
                sender.currentTitle == "ON"
            }
            
        }
```

Кака я написал, так не работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, `==` это оператор сравнения, а не присваивания.
Для смены текста используйте

```
if (sender.tag == 1){
    if isPlaying {
        ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            sender.setTitle("OFF", forState: .Normal)
        })
    } else {
        ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            sender.setTitle("ON", forState: .Normal)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

чтобы поменять текст на кнопке используется

```
setTitle(_:forState:)
```

а не

```
var currentTitle: String? { get }
```

(который, кстати, read-only)